# netbook screen stays black

Tags: display, acer-aspire

I have an acer aspire one netbook. The screen is black but the computer turns on (LED's are on, fan is spinning, etc.)

By black I mean absolutely no backlight. I tried to remove the battery and power it on to "discharge" it (I read that on the Internet, not sure if that ever fixes anything), but no luck. I also tried to replace the RAM stick with another one (which I know for sure is working properly), still no luck. I tried to connect an external monitor and switch to it (fn + f5 on this particular model), still no luck, nothing on the external monitor. I read that flashing the BIOS could fix it (http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/22042-acer-aspire-one-black-screen-of-death), I tried to flash it but basically it doesn't do anything when I power it on with the usb thumb drive. No blinking power button.

To me it sounds like it might be a dead motherboard, a dead RAM slot (there's only one), or the BIOS thing. I would like to rule out the BIOS possibility, but I need help. The reason I ruled out the dead screen possibility is that it did not switch to the external display when I pressed fn + f5, am I wrong by assuming so?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps the backlight has burned out/failed.   Turn on the unit, then shine a flashlight at the screen, you'll be able to see if there's activity on the screen.  Let it run for a moment, it may be trying to perform some cleanup too, since it's been likely booted/rebooted several times unexpectedly.

Comment: Nope, only black pixels, same shade of black everywhere. Can't see anything.

Comment: You can remove the sole SoDIMM and try to boot. If it is a problem with the SoDIMM or something which only occurs when memory is plugged into a broken SoDIMM socket then you have removed the problem and it should try to boot. In this case try to boot means ti starts to boot and then beeps the 'no RAM found' error.